# How to change the playback speed of videos on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, camera-roll

Sometimes it would be nice to not be limited to 1x speed on videos stored in the camera roll of an iOS device, like iPhone.

Is there any simple way of toggling the speed, to say 2x or 3x?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with the photos app/camera roll, but you can very easily do it with the iOS version of iMovie. [Here are the directions apple provides](https://support.apple.com/guide/imovie-iphone/adjust-video-speed-kna47ca84b07/ios).